# Variables access in assembly (MASM32)

Tags: assembly, masm32

As a security university project, I'm supposed to code a PE infector. But I'm a beginner in assembly so I have multiple crash due to my ignorance of how to handle variables.

I know that in a regular program we have a **.data** section for initialized variables, and a **.data?** for uninitialized variables.

But in this case, every tutorial seem to agree that variables should be defined in the **.code** section.

Which leads to something like that:

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
option casemap:none
include \masm32\include\masm32rt.inc
.code
start:
    mov stuff, 1
    ret


stuff dd ?

end start
```

Unfortunately, this causes a segmentation fault, and I can't figure out why.

As another example:

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
option casemap:none
include \masm32\include\masm32rt.inc
.code
start:
    invoke  MessageBoxA, 0, offset hello, offset hello, MB_OK
    ret


hello  db      "Hello buddy", 0

end start
```

This one doesn't compile, as the hello variable is unknown at the compilation (assemble :p) time, which seems legit to me but then... what is the way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most operating systems disallow writes to the code segment, as part of their malware protection. Makes it harder to infect code. :-)

`invoke` is a macro that will likely have to see all its arguments at compile time, so it can be expanded properly. It cannot easily use things that appear later in the code, so you have to make sure it appears earlier. Here, for example, the address of `hello` will depend on the size of the expansion of the macro.

References to data, like in your `mov stuff,1`, has a fixed size and can be fixed-up later. Perhaps in a second pass of the assembler, or by the linker.

Comment: I don't really understand your point. Don't we have relocations exactly for this problem?

Comment: Okay for the invoke, i made some tests and it works, but what about the **stuff** ? I'm not sure to understand what am I supposed to do. Using LOCAL variables ?

Comment: fuz: I ignore what is it

Comment: @FTW - If you are going to use variables you have to put them in a writable segment, like data or stack. Having variables in the code segment indicates that the tutorial uses rather old code. Like from when the 386 was the current processor.

Comment: indeed but I was not able to do that. Anyway I figured out how to solve, just had to set an option to the linker to set the section writable: **/SECTION:.text,EWR** and it works. Thanks for your responses.